# Некорректно работает overflow: hidden при border-radius в сафари

Tags: css

На своей анимации при переключении кружков заметила баг в сафари (проверять в новом сафари на маке): `overflow: hidden` при border-radius не распространяется на дочерние теги. Отсекает так будто нет border-radius.

Comment: Ну ок, а в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: Аня, действительно, можешь вопрос сформулировать? И без исходного кода тебе мало кто поможет. Просьба выкладывать, например, здесь jsfiddle.net

Comment: с проблемой разобралась. вопрос был в том почему не работает overflow: hidden для детей?

вот ответ:
Сама суть ошибки крылась в свойстве transform. Оказывается в safari очень много багов связанных с transform.
При отключении этого свойства всё стало отлично работать.
Вариант с маской не всегда подходит!

Полее подробно ответ [тут](https://toster.ru/q/221895#answer_595889)